# Why does my calculator return true for 2^34 == 2^34 - 1?

Tags: math, floating-point, decimal

*I'm asking this question here because I believe this is more of a programmatic issue than anything else.*

I'm using a TI-84 Plus Sliver Edition calculator that contains logical operators that can test for less-than, greater-than, and equality. I find that when I input the expression:

```
2^34 == 2^34 - 1
```

it gives me a surprising 1 for true. It's worth mentioning that my calculator can't precisely output the result of 2^34. Rather, it uses the exponential notation for it and any other powers greater than 33. Is this a potential factor in the boolean output?

Furthermore, the equality test only returns true if the second expression is subtracting by 1 to 9. When the number is >= 10 it then correctly returns false.

Could it be a rounding error? Why is this expression returning true?

Comment: its a rounding error...

Comment: Don't the TI-84s only have like 8 digits of precision?

Comment: ya 1.99999999999 <---11 of them, is being compared to 2 basically. I would just throw the calculator away.

Comment: Regardless of the precision, the calculator should be able to reduce the expression to (0 == 1) and return `false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculator cant keep track of numbers that large.

Every calculator has a set level of precision (lets say 10 digits). Every answer the calculator gives is rounded so that the answer has that many digits, then it shifts the decimal place as much as it needs to in order to make the number big or small (in your case very large).

Your number is so large that when you subtract 1, that causes a change after the 10th digit. This then gets rounded back to what you started with, and then compared. So naturally, it thinks they are the same number (to the precision it is capable of).